# Can I make a GUI with Visual Studio which reads data from multiple microcontrollers?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, arduino, microcontroller, sensors

First off I nearly know 0 about c# ( But worked with C/C++) .As I asked in title, I want to build a basic GUI with graphs and data storage  with c# via windows form in Visual Studio . I managed to reach the state where i can read data and send data/get feedback to a single microcontroller ( TI Tiva C with energia which uses arduino IDE.). But I need to store the data, plot it real time and do it with multiple sensors/microcontrollers.

Can visual studio do this? If yes, can you show me a few tricks or tutorials that can help me. If no, will something like Labview be better for this?

Comment: How are you communicating with the microcontroller?  If it's through a serial  USB or COM port then you'll probably need a separate port for each microcontroller.

Comment: I am doing it with USB cable till i calibrate the sensors. Then it will be with wireless.

Comment: Use the Firmata library on your Arduino boards and connect to them using https://github.com/SolidSoils/Arduino.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is yes.

I would work off of your C++ knowledge.  Here's how I would set this up.

Create a model class for all the data you need to store.

Create a controller class (or classes) for the microcontrollers you want to connect to.  If they are similar enough this can be the same class, otherwise it's simpler to break them out into their own classes.  (you should have the code for this if you're already reading from one microcontroller).

As for the GUI, this is going to be up to you.  You can combine all the UI pieces you want onto a single window, and display them by checking any time your model class updates or by binding them (check out WPF binding if you'd like to do it this way).  If you're using Windows Forms, I would suggest doing the one-window/all controls route.  If you're using WPF, you can use separate user controls for each microcontroller you want to display, and then combine the usercontrols on a window/however you want.

tl;dr: You can accomplish this by following good coding practices of model, view, controller, (MVC) and learning how to update a GUI from a model class and/or binding.